# Is it possible to "add" to the default copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Is it possible to "add" to the default copy constructor?

Eg. For this class:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int a;
        int* b;
};
```

I want to just write

```
A::A(const A& rvalue):
    a(rvalue.a),
    b(new int(*(rvalue.b)))
{}
```

without the `a(rvalue.a)` part.

(Ignore the bad/ugly code and possible memory leaks)

Comment: This default copy constructor is not trivial

Comment: Why do you need this? Can't you change the class?

Comment: It's just I have a rather large class with just a single pointer (And I can't use smart pointers) so I need to write a copy constructor for it, but most of the copy constructor would be just doing what the default copy constructor would have done

Comment: "Can't use smart pointers" - why not? They're standard C++.

Comment: So why can't you change the class to contain the declaration of the copy constructor?

Comment: If I included the a deceleration, I would need to either fill in the whole constructor, set it to default or make it deleted. What I want is "part" of the default constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you ask for is impossible. Once you declare your own copy constructor the compiler will not generate a copy constructor for you. That means you won't be able to simply add or augment the default copy constructor because it won't exist. It's all or nothing, so to speak.

Comment: Note that this is also yet another reason to avoid doing things (ie: naked pointers) that require writing a copy constructor. Not unless you have no other choice.

Answer (score 5):

it is impossible. However, if you want to reduce redundant code for a large number of "default copied" fields, it may be achieved with intermdiate inheritance:

```
struct A1  {
  int a1;
  int a2;
  // ....
  int aN;
};

struct A:public A1
{
  int* b;
  A(const A& rhs):  A1(rhs), b(new int(*(rhs.b))) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not nartually supported by C++ : you cannot have half default constructor.

But what you want to achieve can be done by the little trick below:

**please note this small demo below have a lot defects(memory leak etc), so it's ONLY for demostration the tentative solution only:**

```
//class A hasa large number date members(but all can take advantage of default 
//copy constructor
struct A{
    A(int i):a(i){}
    int a;
    //much more data memberS can use default copy constructor all in class A
};

//class B is simply wrapper for class A 
//so class B can use the default constructor of A
//while just write copy constructor for a raw pointer in it's copy constructor
//I think this is what OP want ?
struct B
{
    B(int i,int j):m_a(i),m_b(new int(j)){}

    B(const B & rval):
    m_a(rval.m_a),
    m_b(new int(*rval.m_b))
    {
    }
    A     m_a;
    int * m_b;
};

int main()
{
    B c(2,3); // a=2, *m_b=3
    B d(c);   //after copy constructor, a=2, *m_b=3
}
```